# Why can't Android find android.graphics.OpenGLContext?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to compile some OpenGL samples available on the net in SDK 1.5. But the import statement for android.graphics.OpenGLContext gives me an error saying the class cannot be found.

Can someone tell me where I can find this class. And if it is no longer supported by the android SDK then how do I port the samples to 1.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell all of the OpenGL stuff got moved somewhere around version 0.9. It looks like it is mostly contained in the [javax.microedition.khronos.egl](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/egl/package-summary.html) and the [javax.microedition.khronos.opengles](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/package-summary.html) packages now. That said, I think the class you're looking for is [javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/egl/EGLContext.html).

Personally I'd be dubious of relying on any older code/tutorials as Android has undergone some fairly significant changes over the last year.

Comment: The problems is the OpenGL sample code in 1.0 and 1.5 are way different. And most of the samples available on the Internet still use OpenGLContext. Any idea where I can find samples using the 1.5 SDK (other than the API demos of course - have already gone through those)